# defining business day where hours are not same as standard days

Tags: datetime, powerbi, timestamp, dax, timestamp-with-timezone

While working on a sales report for an entertainment company ( bars and nightclubs), I normally just sum sales and I get the daily sum of sales. but I was communicated that their **business day starts at 6 am of each and closes at 5:59:59 am the next day**. basically sales reported Monday are the sales from 6 am Sunday thru 5:59:59 am Monday.
the company operates throughout the US so we have multiple time zones as well
the table has the following columns:
**Transaction id, location, Transaction_datetimeLocal, TransactionDateTimeUTC, Transaction amount**
how do I define / filter the calculation to be  from 6am one day to 5:59:59 am the next day  USING **Power BI / DAX**

TIA

Comment: What's the problem here? Just subtract 6 hours from your local times and you're done. I wonder what UTC is used for ...

Comment: @PeterSmith : the problem is, not an expert here, never worked with time stamps, so I have no clue how to approach it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI you have your table with the local time. You need to add a calculated column with the following DAX formula:

```
Business Time = 'Table'[Local Time] - TIME(6, 0, 0)
```

From this new column you could the create your business date with

```
Business Date = 'Table'[Business Time].[Date]
```

This is how it looks in the Data view:
[image]